# Database error : no such column: connect_connect.reciever_id

Tags: database, django

I have created following model

```
 class ConnectToFrom(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    kiosk = models.ForeignKey(Kiosks, null=True)

 class Connect(models.Model):
    parent_id = models.ForeignKey("self", null = True, blank = True)
    sender = models.ForeignKey(ConnectToFrom, related_name='sent_messages' )
    reciever = models.ForeignKey(ConnectToFrom, related_name='received_messages')
    .
    .
    .
```

I am not able to access Connects to add any connect object through admin site !
Can i not reference same model to two fields ?
I am not able to figure out what exactly is causing the error .
Please help

Traceback :

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://www.example.com:8000/admin/connect/connect/

Django Version: 1.3
Python Version: 2.6.6
Installed Applications:
['broadcast',
 'shastra',
 'fb_api',
 'log',
 'nties',
 'crc',
 'connect',
 'network',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'kiosks',
 'content',
 'home',
 'dashboard',
 'trial',
 'meta',
 'oembed']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
  307.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  93.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  79.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  197.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  28.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  93.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  24.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changelist_view
  1159.             'selection_note': _('0 of %(cnt)s selected') % {'cnt': len(cl.result_list)},
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in __len__
  82.                 self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in iterator
  273.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in results_iter
  680.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  735.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py" in execute
  34.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  234.             return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: DatabaseError at /admin/connect/connect/
Exception Value: no such column: connect_connect.reciever_id
```

Comment: reciever != receiver. Were you consistent in your chosen spelling?

Comment: Ya i have used the same spelling as " reciever " . Although am gonna change it now .

Answer (score 5):

Did you add the `receiver` field to your model after you initially created the `connect_connect` table? If so you'll have to manually add that field to your database (Django does not automatically sync changes to your models with your database.)

Just launch your interactive db shell, usually  `dbshell`, and add the field. In MySQL it would be something like:

```
ALTER TABLE connect_connect ADD COLUMN receiver_id integer;
```

I'd recommend running `manage.py sqlall appname` to see how Django would create your db tables now, and then make sure the db matches that by making the necessary changes through your db shell.

Comment: i dont have any reciever_id field in my model . That is what am surprised about !

Comment: its your `receiver` field. Since it's representing a ForeignField Django creates it in the db as `receiver_id`. If you don't care about the data you already have you can run `manage.py reset appname` to sync your models and your db, otherwise I'd recommend running `manage.py sqlall appname` to see how Django would create your db tables now, and then make sure the db matches that by making the necessary changes through your db shell.

Comment: Its showing reciever_id as a field when i do sqlall as :                  "reciever_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "connect_connecttofrom" ("id")

Comment: it should, since `receiver` is clearly in your model now. you now need to launch your db interactive shell and use those SQL statements to add that and all related fields so that your db and your models are in sync.

Comment: Wonderful answer just helped me 4 months later. Thank you sir!