# Why might django not create a database column specified by manage.py sql

Tags: database, django

I'm trying to create an app where all data belongs to exactly one user, and users only axcess their own data (e.g. email).  I model this in my models.py file like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
...

class Foo(models.Model):
    owner=ForeignKey(User, related_name='foos')
```

which seems to work fine.

```
python manage.py sql appFoo
```

displays sql including

```
CREATE TABLE "appFoo_foo" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "owner_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id")
    ...
```

The problem, though, arises when I try to delete users I have created for testing purposes, both using

```
User.objects.exclude(username='root').delete()
```

and using the built-in django admin app.  In either case I get a database error saying that the table appFoo_foo has no column named owner_id.  This is after running syncdb.  Any thoughts as to why this might happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I swear I looked for related questions before asking this one, but I didn't see [Database error : no such column: connect_connect.reciever_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913782/database-error-no-such-column-connect-connect-reciever-id) until after I asked it.  My problem was the same.  Basically, I added a field to my model and expected syncdb to modify the database accordingly, but apparently it doesn't.  I had to run

```
manage.py reset appFoo
```

followed by syncdb again, and it worked like a charm.

Edit: I'm just now reading that reset is deprecated and you can use flush instead.